# Is there a firewall that returns html instead of just rejecting the incoming HTTP request?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, firewall, webserver

Is it possible to return an HTML response like below instead of just rejecting the connection:

You are bared from accesing this IP

I understand there are ways to filter the incoming IP addresses at the web server level but was wondering if it was possible to do it before the request reaches the web server.

Comment: Don't think so. You would need to make something yourself and use it as a connector between the two. And I would suggest not using html but json. Far easier to accomplish using python.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating further? I am not really sure where to begin, any hint will do

Comment: I send those type of replies all the time, but do it via the webserver via rewrite rules.

Comment: What I trying to do is prevent request reaching the web server to protect it but at the same time let the other end know why they have been rejected.